# How much heap memory required for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 8 node cluster(3Master+3Data+2Coordinate) in each data node the heap size is 10gb and disk space is 441gb each total 1.2TB
in each day i have 32.73GB data in each day 26 shards created for 11 indices.So lets suppose the retention period is 30 days.In 30th day the data on cluster would be 982GB and total shards would be 780 each node gets 260 shards.So the average shard size would be 260mb(approx).i read  [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-count-recommendation) documentation that a node of 30gb heap size can handle 600 shards.**So the question is Can heap size of 10gb can handle 260 shards ?**.

Answer (score 1):

This article which you read can be considered a good general recommendations but there are various factors which can affect it, like size of indices, size of shards, size of documents, type of disk, current load on the system and so on, in the same document you can notice the shard size recommendation is between 10 to 50 GB, while you have very small shard size(260 MB as you mentioned), so based on this, I can say 10GB heap can easily handle 260 shards in your case, although you should benchmark your cluster and read more about how ES internally stores the data and searches them so that its easy for you to fine-tune it.